# Getting the Current font of a NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How would I get the current font of an NSTextView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `NSTextView` is a kind of `NSText`. So, send it [a `font` message](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSText/font).

Answer (score 9):

Peter's answer is correct but is not the whole story. Calling `-font` on the `NSTextView` will return the font of the first character in the text view's string, or if the text view is empty it will return the font at the insertion point.

However, if the text view is configured to accept rich text, the text view can have several different fonts.

In that case, you would need to obtain the font from a specific location in the text view's `NSTextStorage` object, which is a subclass of `NSAttributedString`. You obtain the `NSTextStorage` object by calling `-textStorage` on the text view.

You can get the font at a particular location in the `NSTextStorage` object by using the `-attribute:atIndex:effectiveRange:` method of `NSAttributedString` and passing in `NSFontAttributeName` for the attribute parameter.

Comment: That's a good answer but my text view is only going to have one font through out so Peter's answer is what I need. Thanks.